# Publishing data on java 9 Flow to subscribers in a way that only one subscriber will consume it

Tags: java, java-9, java-flow

Is there a way to publish data to subscribers in a way that only one subscriber will receive it ?
What i am trying to achieve is that the subscriber publisher model will work as a queue that has multiple readers but one publisher.
Once the publisher will publish data, the first subscriber that receives it, will be the only one that will process it.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You're asking about [`java.util.concurrent.Flow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Flow.html), right? Perhaps you should mention that in the question *text*.

Answer (score 5):

In reactive streams (at least, in their `java.util.concurrent.Flow` incarnation), subscribers just ask for data, and only the publisher is in control of how to publish that data.

The only general purpose implementation of `Flow.Publisher` that exists in Java 9 is `SubmissionPublisher` that follows the standard pub/sub way of publishing any published item to all the subscribers. I did not find any easy way to hack `SubmissionPublisher` to make it only publish to one subscriber.

But you could try to write your own `Flow.Publisher` implementation, something like this:

```
class QueueLikePublisher<T> implements Publisher<T> {
    private final ExecutorService executor = ForkJoinPool.commonPool(); // daemon-based
    private List<QueueLikeSubscription<? super T>> subscriptions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public synchronized void subscribe(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
        // subscribing: adding a new subscription to the list
        QueueLikeSubscription<? super T> subscription = new QueueLikeSubscription<>(subscriber, executor);
        subscriptions.add(subscription);
        subscriber.onSubscribe(subscription);
    }

    public void submit(T item) {
        // we got some data: looking for non-completed and demanding
        // subscription and give it the data item

        for (QueueLikeSubscription<? super T> subscription : subscriptions) {
            if (!subscription.completed && subscription.demand > 0) {
                subscription.offer(item);
                // we just give it to one subscriber; probaly offer() call needs
                // to be wrapped in a try/catch
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    static class QueueLikeSubscription<T> implements Subscription {
        private final Subscriber<? super T> subscriber;
        private final ExecutorService executor;
        volatile int demand = 0;
        volatile boolean completed = false;

        QueueLikeSubscription(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber,
                ExecutorService executor) {
            this.subscriber = subscriber;
            this.executor = executor;
        }

        public synchronized void request(long n) {
            if (n != 0 && !completed) {
                if (n < 0) {
                    IllegalArgumentException ex = new IllegalArgumentException();
                    executor.execute(() -> subscriber.onError(ex));
                } else {
                    // just extending the demand
                    demand += n;
                }
            }
        }

        public synchronized void cancel() {
            completed = true;
        }

        Future<?> offer(T item) {
            return executor.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    subscriber.onNext(item);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

It publishes the item to the first subscriber that is not yet completed (for example, cancelled) and that has non-zero demand.

Please note that this code is *just an outline for illistrative purposes to demonstrate the idea*. For example, it should probably contain more exception handling (like handling the `RejectedExecutionException`).

Comment: In case call to `QueueLikePublisher#submit` occur before any call to  `QueueLikePublisher#subscribe`, the data item is lost. This is hardly what user expects.

Answer (score 1):

The case when only one subscriber should receive every data item is common. For example, subscribers can be database connections and data items - requests to a database, and the publisher - the central entry point to the whole connection pool. It is a different data exchange protocol, so using interfaces from j.u.c.Flow may be confusing.

Generally, those interfaces can be used for this master-worker protocol, but there is a subtle but important difference: subscribers should not request more than one data item at a time. Otherwise, one worker can take several items while other workers would sit without work. So the method `Subscription#request()` can be removed from interface. It is assumed that by the act of subscribing, the subscriber agrees to accept one data item. As soon as that item is submitted to the subscriber, subscriber is unsubscribed. This allows not to scan the list of subscriptions trying to find acceptable subscriber (as in the @Roman Puchkovskiy implementation) but submit next data item to the first subscribed subscriber. As soon as subscriber needs more data, it subscribes again. This is exactly how worker threads in a thread pool request next tasks.

Since the method `cancel()` remains the only method in `Subscription`, we can replace it with new method `Publisher#cancel(Subscriber)` and eliminate `Subscription` interface entirely. The method `Subscriber#onSubscribe(Subscription)` is replaced then with the method`Subscriber#onSubscribe(Publisher)`.

I am developing an asynchronous library (it is not yet of production quality) which contains the solution for your use case: class [PickPoint](https://github.com/akaigoro/async-tutorial/blob/master/src/main/java/org/df4j/async/tutorial/node/messagestream/PickPoint.java).